# iOS Xamarin UIView Fill Based on Parent

Tags: ios, xamarin

Coming from WPF I'm very used to not having to worry about sizing controls explicitly. How can I do this in iOS using Xamarin? What I'm looking for is a way to set UIViews to fill all the available space it has (and of course automatically update if the parent's size changes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the UIView property AutoresizingMask

This dictates how the UIView is resized when its parent changes size.  It defaults to UIViewAutoResizing.None.  But you can you a bitwise comparison to change what sides/margins you want to adjust during resize.

Xamarin API for [UIViewAutoResizing](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewAutoresizing)